# Toggle between two network ports Java

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, publish-subscribe

I am trying to send a message from publisher file (sending on port 8000) which is received by Server (listening on port 5000 and 8000)and which forwards the message to the subscriber(listening on port 5000). The problem is that, communication between publisher and server is fine, however, I am not able to forward the message to the subscriber because the server is still listening to publisher and toggling to the subscriber port and forwarding the message. Any suggestion is appretiated

**Publisher**

```
   package serverclient;
   import java.net.*;
   import java.io.*;

   public class Publisher {
      public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",8000);

    // reading from keyboard (keyRead object)
    BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // sending to client (pwrite object)
    OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream(); 
    PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);

    InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

    System.out.println("Start the chitchat, type and press Enter key");

    String receiveMessage,sendMessage;               
    while(true)
    {
        sendMessage = keyRead.readLine();  // keyboard reading
        pwrite.println(sendMessage);       // sending to server
        pwrite.flush();                    // flush the data  

        if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) //receive from server
        {
            System.out.println(receiveMessage); // displaying at DOS prompt
        }  
        else{
            System.out.print("Null");
        }
    }

}
    }
```

**Subscriber**

```
  package serverclient;

  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import java.net.Socket;


   public class Subscriber {
      public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);

  // receiving from server ( receiveRead  object)
    InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

    System.out.println("Recive side");
    System.out.print("Connection Status: " + sock.isConnected() + "  " + sock.getPort());

    String receiveMessage, sendMessage;  
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("Hey man " + receiveRead.readLine() + "\n");
        if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null) //receive from server
        {
            System.out.println(receiveMessage); // displaying at DOS prompt
            break;
        }  
        else{
            System.out.print("Null");
        }
    }

}
 }
```

**Server**

```
 package serverclient;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;

 public class Server extends Thread{
     private Socket socket;
     private int clientNumber;

public Server(Socket socket, int clientNumber){
    this.socket  = socket;
    this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    if(socket.getLocalPort() == 5000)System.out.print("\nSubscriber "+ clientNumber +" is connected to the server");
    if(socket.getLocalPort() == 8000)System.out.print("\nPublisher "+ clientNumber +" is connected to the server");
} 

@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        BufferedReader dStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        System.out.print("\nSocket Address "+ socket.getLocalPort() + "   " + socket.getPort());

        while(true){
            if ( socket.getInputStream().available() != 0 && socket.getLocalPort() == 8000 ){
                synchronized(this){
                    String clMessage = dStream.readLine();
                    System.out.println(clMessage);
                    out.println("Hey the publisher has sent the message :  " + clMessage);

                }
            }else if (socket.getInputStream().available() != 0 && socket.getLocalPort() == 5000 ){
                out.println("Hey man I am so good");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.print("\nError has been handled 1\n");
    }finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.print("\nError has been handled 2\n");
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    int subNumber = 0;
    int pubNumber = 0;
    ServerSocket servSockpub = new ServerSocket(8000);   
    ServerSocket servSocksub = new ServerSocket(5000);
    try {
        while (true) {
            Server servpub = new Server(servSockpub.accept(),++pubNumber);
            servpub.start();
            System.out.print("\nThe server is running on listen port "+ servSockpub.getLocalPort());
            Server servsub = new Server(servSocksub.accept(),++subNumber);
            servsub.start();
            System.out.print("\nThe server is running on listen port "+ servSocksub.getLocalPort());
        }
    } finally {
        servSockpub.close();
        servSocksub.close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We need to see some code as to what you’ve done

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the server ports (no duplicates/collisions).

But you have no code whatsoever that bridges data between the 2 sockets.

Basically, you should have 1 server that receives the 2 sockets and move data across in1-out2.

Careful too, in your code you can only connect a subscriber once the publisher has connected.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do that.